# Possible to add a tab space to app description in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I've been able to add the special character for a bullet point in my app description, but can't figure out how to add a tab space or if it's even possible. Does anyone know? Trying to format my description to make it look a little nicer.

Comment: There is **no** way you can add a tab character. If people could format with nicer characters, you would find that formatting in the description of famous apps such as Clash of Clans or Angry Birds. Furthermore, Apple recently started to reject app descriptions with Emoji in them.

Comment: @lnjuanj - why dont you write this as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no** way you can add a tab character. If people could format with nicer characters, you would find that formatting in the description of famous apps such as Clash of Clans or Angry Birds. Furthermore, Apple recently started to reject app descriptions with Emoji in them.